# Qt Designer + PyQt 5, не получается сделать обработку события

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Помогите пожалуйста новичку. Сделал виджет в *Qt Designer*, перевел его в **`.py`** файл. Хочу привязать обработку события к кнопке через `clicked.connect()`, но почему то не работает, ошибку не выдает.

Вот код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(226, 216)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 181, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setText("")
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 47, 13))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 226, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ok"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def on_click():
    print('Click')

form.pushButton.clicked.connect(on_click)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. **Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(226, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 181, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 226, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ok"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))


#создаем класс, который наследуется от виджета и заполняем его минимальной логикой
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        
        # Тут ваша логика
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        

    def on_click(self):
        print('Click')
        self.label.setText(f'<h3>{self.lineEdit.text()}</h3>')
        self.label.adjustSize()   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()

    w = MainWindow()  
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())           #   После этой строки
print('Это вы не увидите никогда.') #   <----
    

def on_click():
    print('Click')

form.pushButton.clicked.connect(on_click)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался